# Creating my first app as described on DjangoBook

Tags: django

I'm reading the DjangoBook version 2.0, and i've just created my first app and added it to INSTALLED_APPS setting attribute in settings.py

I've created this app using :

> python manage.py startapp books

therefore, it's name is 'books'.

**[EDIT: fixed the models code]**

i added the models as written on the book,

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

After validating the added app, using

> python manage.py validate

I receive the following output:

> Error: No module named books

*** The data i added to INSTALLED_APPS is 'mysite.books' because my project's name is mysite.

What is wrong with my actions ?

Comment: DjangoBook is outdated, you should refer to Django's current [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/)

Comment: thanks. i followed the doc' and now it's working.

Comment: @Matan, you should answer your question and accept it if you have already figured out what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

http://thedjangoforum.com/board/thread/1180/python-managepy-validate-error-no-mod/

here is the answer. it solved my problem.

"you should change 'mysite.books', into 'books' after that your problem will end"

try it!