# Unable to validate my app on Django

Tags: python, django, validation

I am reading Django Documentation and just created my first app using the command:

```
python manage.py startapp books
```

and modified the models.py file as mentioned in the book.

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
   state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   website = models.URLField()

class Author(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
   publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
   publication_date = models.DateField()
```

Then I added this newly created app 'books' to the INSTALLED_APPS list in the settings.py file. Initially I added 'mysite.books' to the list and python manage.py validate returned the following error:

```
Error: No module named books.
```

I referred to one of the questions from stackoverflow [Creating my first app as described on DjangoBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489905/creating-my-first-app-as-described-on-djangobook) and tried implementing the solution by changing 'mysite.books' to 'books'. Now, when I run python manage.py validate, I get the following output:

```
Unknown command: 'validate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Comment: Hi, i dont think you have to do validate, once you aded it in your Installed apps, test it with manage.py runserver

Comment: try also makemigrations and migrate if you want your changes to be written in the database

Comment: When I test it with manage.py runserver, I get the following error:    RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Is your question about installed apps or a `validate` command? You should probably include your installed apps if the former

Comment: Are you following djangobook.com ? If so, it is extremely out of date and should not be used. You should follow the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: Hi Burhan Khalid, Yes I have been using the djangobook.com. Thanks for the help, I will follow this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't use 'mysite.blablabla' on your installed apps. use only 'books'

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (#'mysite.books',
                   'books')
```

then type on your commend line:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

It will create your model's tables on your db.

in your admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Publisher, Author, Book
admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

type on command line it will help you to create admin account:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

then after filling the superuser info type on command line

```
python manage.py runserver
```

finally go on your browser and login: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

you will see your models on your admin page.
Hope this helps. happy coding